# Why is "Log in with facebook" button hidden in spotify Auth example

Tags: javascript, facebook, spotify

I was trying out a simple Spotify Web API authorization code example. Later i noticed that when the login page opens, the "Login with Facebook" button is not being display on the page.

The same can be found on the actual example code they have posted on `jsfiddle` at [Playlist Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4v3h/78/)

Does any one know how to enable the "Login with facebook" button again?

Comment: I just tried the Playlist Demo you linked to and it works fine - I see a big, blue "Login with Facebook" button above the login fields. Perhaps there was a temporary glitch.

Comment: i tried it now. It still is not showing the button for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because i had AdBlock enabled on my browser.Once i disabled that, it was working fine. :-\